# Interactive python 3d plot in jupyter notebook within VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

When I use jupyter notebook in Chrome, I had the opportunity to show interactive 3d plots, like this:
[image]

Now I would like to see the same result in the VSCode. Are there any solutions to this thing?

The same code in the VSCode:
[image]

Comment: what's test_model, would you mind posting the code?

Comment: it does not matter as my question is about other thing

Comment: Have you installed the module IPython?

Comment: Now `%matplotlib widget` should work with the VSCode Jupyter extension, but you need to install the `ipympl` package: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64614116/9105334

Comment: @tueda You should provide this as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `%matplotlib widget` instead of `%matplotlib notebook`.

Comment: Sadly,  this throws an exception for me.

Comment: I had the same problem, tried that, but the plot does not appear neither in line nor on a separate window