# Animate / update a matplotlib plot in VS Code notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Using Jupyter Notebook, I can create an animated plot (based on [this sample code](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/animation/simple_anim.html)):

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

def init():
    line.set_ydata([np.nan] * len(x))
    return line,

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(x + i / 100))  # update the data.
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=2, blit=True, save_count=50)

plt.show()
```

Is it possible to do so in Visual Studio Code's notebook editor? I think it involves the magic `%matplotlib notebook` mode which VS Code does not seem to support, but I don't know if there is an alternative.

Comment: [This blog post](http://louistiao.me/posts/notebooks/embedding-matplotlib-animations-in-jupyter-notebooks/) talks about how to render an animation to an HTML5 plot that gets embedded, but this is not my goal: my plot will be updated based on a live data feed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looks as though vscode supports ipywidgets (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3429). So you can use the [ipympl](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/) backend to matplotlib.

To use it you can use the `%matplotlib ipympl` magic.

---

`%matplotlib notebook` does some javascript injection that is very specific to jupyter notebook, so it will not work in vscode or even jupyter lab.

Comment: This seems to work! The backend name might be `widget` now but `ipympl` also works.

Comment: `widget` and `ipympl` are aliases for eachother in the ipython source. I'm not sure if either is explicitly preferred.

Comment: You may also need to install support for it e.g. `pip install ipympl`

Comment: I tried that, and neither the widget nor ipympl show the plot...