# Uncrop 3d plots in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, matplotlib-3d, z-axis

I'm doing some 3d scatter plots with jupyter notebooks in VSCode, and they aren't showing properly.

[image: 3d scatter plot from docs]

I went to the documentation in matlab and downloaded the jupyter notebook for the [3d scatter plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html) and tried running that in vscode, getting the same results, the z label gets cut off.

I've seen a lot of questions about making the plot interactive with matplotlib magic, and some of those solutions (`%matplotlib qt`) do work (the image isn't cropped anymore, but gets created in a separate window. I want the plot to be inline, because I'm doing a lot of them and having one 40 windows created every time is a mess.

I've tried the magic `%matplotlib widget` and `%matplotlib notebook`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64331140/interactive-python-3d-plot-in-jupyter-notebook-within-vscode), and the `%matplotlib ipympl` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64613706/animate-update-a-matplotlib-plot-in-vs-code-notebook/64614116#64614116) but when I use those the plot stops showing, appearing only after I change to `%matplotlib inline` and showing any plot I've done before at that point (all cropped).

**I've also checked the code in jupyter lab and it does not have this problem, the image shows completely fine, so it seems to be a problem with Jupyter notebooks in VsCode.**

I'm not trying to change the position of the z axis, It's fine where it is, I just want to make the image bigger so the z label is shown properly.

Just in case, I've tried the comment of [Trenton McKinney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7758804/trenton-mckinney) of doing `ax.zaxis._axinfo['juggled'] = (1, 2, 2)` to change the z-label to the other side, and it still gets cut, just in the other side of the image.

[image: 3d scatter plot from docs with the z axes on the other side]

So it's not an issue of where the z axes and label are.

PS: As requested, I put the from the example here for ease of use.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    """
    Helper function to make an array of random numbers having shape (n, )
    with each number distributed Uniform(vmin, vmax).
    """
    return (vmax - vmin)*np.random.rand(n) + vmin

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

n = 100

# For each set of style and range settings, plot n random points in the box
# defined by x in [23, 32], y in [0, 100], z in [zlow, zhigh].
for m, zlow, zhigh in [('o', -50, -25), ('^', -30, -5)]:
    xs = randrange(n, 23, 32)
    ys = randrange(n, 0, 100)
    zs = randrange(n, zlow, zhigh)
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, marker=m)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

**Update:** I've posted an issue in the github VSCode repo, link [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/13661)

**Update on the update:** The issue has been found to be a matplotlib/jupyter problem, so I've opened a new issue in the matplotlib repo, link [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/26465)

Comment: The issue has to do with being an inline plot, not necessarily the coding environment. The label can be move to the other arm with `ax.zaxis._axinfo['juggled'] = (1, 2, 2)`

Comment: The plot renders correctly if not rendering inline. Switch to interactive mode with `%matplotlib qt` works in Jupyter.  `%matplotlib inline` to switch back in inline mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after a pair of issues in github, I've finally found an answer. I'll leave [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/26465#issuecomment-1669679047) the answer in github for reference

It appears the problem is caused by the default inline backend saving the figure with `bbox_inches= 'tight'` which causes the code to crop the image. this can be solved using the inline magic

`%config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'bbox_inches':None}`

which overthrows the default and gives you a nice, big image with plenty of room for labels and everything else. In case this doesn't work (the image created is rather big) I leave [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-matplotlib) the link to the docs.

Another option is to add padding, which can be done with the magic

`%config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'pad_inches': .3}`

This option might need some trial and error to get the size right. In my case 0.3 worked as a charm.